# Need to serialize as JSON string using multiple separate keys in POJO using jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, pojo

I have a java class as mentioned below, In that, I want to create an inner JSON using duration & durationType while serialization using Jackson.

```
public class Task {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Integer duration;
private String durationType

// getters & setters...
```

If I serialize (POJO to JSON String) I need output as following, without creating a duration class.

```
{
    "id" : 1001,
    "name" : "Task title"
    "duration" : {
        "value" : 4
        "type" : "hours"
    }
}
```

If it is that possible, please let me know. Thanks in advance :)